# DIV scrollTop until second to last div bottom

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to do a sticky div that follow the scroll until the second to last div bottom (the bottom of the green div of this [pen](http://codepen.io/paolopolix/pen/wWRjpW))

```
function stickyScroll() {

  var scroll_from_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var initial_scroll = $('.right_sticky').offset().top-111;
  var width = $('right_sticky').parent().width();

  if(scroll_from_top >= initial_scroll) {
    $('.right_sticky').css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'width': width,
      'top': '0',
      'margin-top': '111px'
    });
  } else {
    $('.right_sticky').css({
      'position': 'relative',
      'width': width,
      'top': '0',
      'margin-top': '40px'
    });
  }
}

stickyScroll();

$(window).scroll( function() {
  stickyScroll();
});
```